# Can't install CUDA on Ubuntu due to Nouveau - how can I disable / uninstall?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, nouveau

I note that I sometimes get weird Nouveau problems in the command line.

I tried to disable Nouveau using the instructions [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#runfile-nouveau-ubuntu), but I still get all of the problems below.

Trying to install CUDA 7.5, I get the following:

[image: http://imgur.com/wt8b9Av]

Here's the contents of the log file:

```
daniel@DansCPU:/var/log$ more nvidia-installer.log 
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Fri Jun  3 15:13:32 2016
installer version: 352.39

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer
    --ui=none
    --no-questions
    --accept-license
    --disable-nouveau

Using built-in stream user interface
-> Detected 4 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 4.
-> License accepted by command line option.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 352.39.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
ERROR: The Nouveau kernel driver is currently in use by your system.  This driver is incompatible with the NVIDIA driver, and must be disabled before proceeding.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver README an
d your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
WARNING: One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau are already present at: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf.  Please be sure you have rebooted your system since these
 files were written.  If you have rebooted, then Nouveau may be enabled for other reasons, such as being included in the system initial ramdisk or in your X configuration file.  Please consult the NVIDIA d
river README and your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.
-> For some distributions, Nouveau can be disabled by adding a file in the modprobe configuration directory.  Would you like nvidia-installer to attempt to create this modprobe file for you? (Answer: Yes)
-> One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau have been written.  For some distributions, this may be sufficient to disable Nouveau; other distributions may require modification of the ini
tial ramdisk.  Please reboot your system and attempt NVIDIA driver installation again.  Note if you later wish to reenable Nouveau, you will need to delete these files: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-dis
able-nouveau.conf
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver downl
oad page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Comment: Remove the files located in /usr/local/cuda-5.0 In that directory contains the Cuda files, delete them, and Cuda will be uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot to a console to do this.

1. Boot and hold the shift key
2. Select Ubuntu and press "E"
3. Add nouveau.modeset=0 to the bottom of the boot settings
4. Press F10
5. From this console, blacklist nouveau, and re-install your nvidia packages. Try using the nvidia packages like `nvidia-361` - you can google the drivers PPA to find 367. What card are you trying to support?

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up a console and use the command `sudo service lightdm stop` to do the same thing, but I'm unsure if this unloads the nouveau kernel module.